# Maven issue in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Eclipse Oxygen to create a maven application. I am getting an error,
attached are the screenshots of the steps I took. Hope someone can help, thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you checked that you are using the right settings.xml file?

Comment: Delete your .m2 folder and restart the eclipse. The path for the same in windows id C:\Users\<User Name>\.m2

Comment: My assumption is that you have network/firewall/proxy issues...which means you are not allowed to connect to Central repository...I recommend to try on plain command line first...

Comment: @Stultuske how do I find out what the right 'settings.xml' file is in the first place?

Comment: @javaperson as @Stultuske suggested type mvn -X in cmd. if you look closely you'll find something like this `[DEBUG] Reading global settings from c:\....\apache-maven-3.0.3\conf\settings.xml`

Comment: @RamachandraReddy I followed your suggestion and it works. Thanks everyone for helping, deeply appreciate it.